# Accept cookies with SeleniumBasic on IBM website

Tags: vba, selenium

I have VBA code that enters [www.ibm.com](http://www.ibm.com).

There is a cookies consent window I want to bypass.
[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1At6b.png)

I tried to click on the accept button by Xpath but I get error.

> Run-time Error 7:
> NoSuchElementError
> Element not found for XPath=/html/body/div[8]/div[1]/div/div[3]/a[1]

[rendered error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVuCC.png)

I tried to wait until it fully loads, but still no success.

Here is my attempt:

```vb
Dim driver
Set driver = CreateObject("Selenium.EdgeDriver")

With driver
    .start
    .get "https://ibm.com"
    .FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[8]/div[1]/div/div[3]/a[1]").Click
    .Quit
End With
```

I found something about a switch to frame but I do not know how to perform.

Comment: Surprisingly I don't get the cookies consent window while accessing manually even for the first time.

Comment: Try incognito window.

Comment: Nopes, not even there in incognito

Comment: Hmm, could that be by some setting or addin? (I use 'I dont care about cookies'). Did you try also open with selenium? I get it there always.

Comment: Nopes, not even with WebDriver and Python clients

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your button is inside a frame, so you could something like this:

```
Sub CloseConsent()
    With New ChromeDriver
        .get "http://hcad.org/quick-search/"
        .SwitchToFrame .FindElementByXPath("//iframe[@class='truste_popframe']", timeout:=10000)
        .FindElementByXPath("//a[@class='call']", timeout:=10000).Click
    End With
End Sub
```